# How do I install Lean in Visualstudio Code

Tags: visual-studio

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, and it is probably a very basic question, but I cannot find out how to do this.

NOTE: I don't think I've ever installed any extensions to visualstudio code or something similar before. **I am a beginner.**

---

My problem is: I just downloaded the lean prover for windows from here: https://github.com/leanprover/lean/releases/tag/v3.4.1
But I don't know how to install it so I can use it in visual studio code.

It gives me a folder with two .exe files:
lean.exe, and leanchecker.exe

For both of those files, if I try to open them, it opens the command prompt for about 1/10th of a second, then closes it, and then nothing happens.

I have heard that programmers use the so called "command prompt" to install stuff like this, but I know nothing about it, and I don't know where to find info on this. **Could you point me to an explanation of how to install this kind of thing for a beginner?**

(note, the makers of lean say they don't have time to help people with this).

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jroesch.lean When it is so easy to learn how to install from the Marketplace, don't let "a beginner" be the excuse.

Comment: @LexLi, I already tried this and this is an older version of Lean, and it doesn't seem to work. The newest version is only available as a zip package.

Comment: The VSCode extension does have its own documentation, https://github.com/leanprover/vscode-lean#requirements Clearly where to install Lean is documented.